set.getState is not a function in React while trying to use Zustand
I am new to react and states. I am trying to use Zustand to manage my global states. I created a store where I have three function, fetchTodos, where I fetch my data from a Json file (my data is an array of objects, id, title and completed). The second function is called handleAddItem, where I am trying to update the state of my array so I can add a new item to said array. The third function is handleToggleCompleted, this function helps me toggle a checkbox field depending on the value of completed. The error I am getting is "set.getState is not a function" whenever I try to add a new item.
I would appreciate the help or pointing me to the right docs to read.
This is my code for my store:
import {create} from 'zustand';

const useTodoStore = create((set) => ({
  toDoList: [],
  newItem: '', // Input value for new item

  // Fetch data
  fetchTodos: async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
      const todos = await response.json();
      set({ toDoList: todos });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching todos:', error);
    }
  },

  // Actions for updating state
  handleAddItem: (title) => {
    title.preventDefault();

    const newId = Math.max(...set.getState().toDoList.map((todo) => todo.id)) + 1;
    const newTodoItem = { id: newId, title, completed: false };
    set({ toDoList: [...set.getState().toDoList, newTodoItem], newItem: '' });
  },

  handleToggleCompleted: (id) =>
    set((state) => ({
      toDoList: state.toDoList.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      ),
    })),
  setNewItem: (value) => set({ newItem: value }),
}));

export default useTodoStore;


You have to use get().item in case of fetching state instead of set.getState().item
Here is an article for reference:
https://medium.com/globant/react-state-management-b0c81e0cbbf3
